# Mac connecting to WiFi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, mac

I have a network, with several devices on such as windows computers, consoles etc.
I want to connect my Mac to this network. 
I can guarantee the network is working an operational as I have other devices using it (win10 pc & iOS)

The password was correct, the SSID was correct etc. I tried removing the networks from memory on the Mac and reconnecting, I couldnt find and specific settings on the mac that could be causing the issue.

I created another guest network and the mac connected to it and it picked up a DHCP lease i had made for it, so it's not DHCP,
I also tried different DNS settings, public DNS as well as the default gateway. 
Are there some settings (on the router) that might have prevented the Mac from connecting to it? Such as protected management frames etc?

- The MacOs is Catalina and fully updated
- The Mac can connect to the guest Wifi and other Wifi

Like I said previously the windows computer connects ok, as well as my iPhone.

Comment: Try updating the wireless card in your Mac. Update the firmware in your Router.

Comment: The Mac can connect to other WiFi networks and everything else on the router is fine.

Comment: The only other thing (I have had myself) is an incompatibility between device and router. There must be something at issue or it would work.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. I created an additional guest network (more simplified) and it connected straight away. Im missing something within the settings of the router but I cannot fathom a clue as to what it might be. My iphone connects to the original network. 
Curious if someone knows some sort of difference in network settings

Comment: Look at router wireless settings for WEP, WPA2, and AES and see if all are using the same Wireless protocol settings.

Comment: all are as they should be.
With windows releasing an dhcp lease is just ipconfig /release then /renew
What's the equivalent on mac?

Comment: Look in Click on the Apple logo (top left corner), click System Preferences. ... for network settings and release. If this is not for you, search for Release IP on Mac OS.